# Need to remove points based on the return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table, Table "Voucher" has list of all the voucher gained by the customer. Table "ValueToRemove" has the detail of last used voucher value(but don't have detail of voucher used).

In Voucher table I have multiple voucher created for a customer based on the purchase. When I redeem a voucher I don't have control on which voucher I was redeeming, I just store the value and customer detail. Based on this I need to void/remove value of the voucher in "Voucher" table in FIFO method.

```
Table Vocuher
Customer  Voucher date       value    
A         VOC1    20/01/2023 200
A         VOC2    12/03/2023 350
A         VOC3    03/05/2023 200
```

```
PointsToRemove
Customer  Value
A         400
```

Based on above example, Customer has used 400 on the last purchase. So I need to remove this 400 from the voucher table. 200 from VOC1 and 200 from VOC2.

So at the end of the sales, I should have below in my Voucher table

```
Customer  Voucher date       value
A         VOC1    20/01/2023 0
A         VOC2    12/03/2023 150
A         VOC3    03/05/2023 200
```

If someone can help, please let me know how I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what you have already attempted, as well as how you're programmatically accessing the database (as presumably this is some application querying and modifying the data)

Comment: "Table "ValueToRemove" has the detail of last used voucher value" <-- This sounds like a bad database design to me - why are you storing _only_ the last voucher used? What happens to the previous-last-voucher info once a customer uses a new voucher?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I have to do this using sql triggers, as I have no option in the application.

Comment: Who says you have to use triggers? Is this a DB homework assignment or something? (FWIW, my organization generally prohibits triggers because they wreck DB performance - and a disturbingly large number of people who write triggers are blissfully ignorant of the concept of multi-row updates - yikes... triggers: just say no)

Comment: _"When I redeem a voucher I don't have control on which voucher I was redeeming, I just store the value and customer detail."_ - how do you know the value of the voucher if you don't have any way of identifying the voucher-code or similar identifier? Do your users just enter the cash-value of the voucher and that's it? If so, then you have a fundamentally broken design in your software: the only real solution is to require users to enter a voucher identifier.

Comment: @Dai, it's not super unusual, sometimes the POS system only expose total number of available points, and you just say how much you wanna use

Comment: @siggemannen Right, but they're called "POS systems" for a reason ;)

Comment: Lol @Dai, indeed i've worked on couple of those :D Voucher systems are complicated, especially the returns, hopefully i'll never go back to that!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to calculate cumulative sum of the `Voucher Value` and then compare with the `total redemption value` (from `PointsToRemove`) to determine the redemption value by Voucher. And finally update back to the `Voucher` table.

This is how the cte (`redemption`) result looks like

| Customer | Voucher | Date | Value | CumValue | TotalRedeem | Redeem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | VOC1 | 2023-01-20 | 200 | 200 | 400 | 200 |
| A | VOC2 | 2023-03-12 | 350 | 550 | 400 | 200 |
| A | VOC3 | 2023-05-03 | 200 | 750 | 400 | 0 |

```
with 
redemption as
(
  select v.Customer, v.Voucher, v.Date, v.[Value],
         TotalRedeem = r.[Value],
         Redeem = case  when sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer 
                                                      order by v.[Date])
                        <=   r.[Value]
                        then v.[Value]
                        when sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer 
                                                      order by v.[Date])
                        -    v.[Value] <= r.[Value]
                        then r.[Value] 
                        -    sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer  
                                                      order by v.[Date])
                        +    v.[Value]
                        else 0
                        end
  from   Vocuher v
         inner join PointsToRemove r on v.Customer = r.Customer
  where  v.[Value] > 0
)
update r
set    [Value] = r.[Value] - r.Redeem
from   redemption r
```

Note that you need to delete from the `PointsToRemove` table after update `Voucher` table

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kZ8bGyq_)

You can modify this easily to trigger (if this is what you wants)

```
create trigger update_redemption
on PointsToRemove for insert
as
begin
  
    with 
    redemption as
    (
      select v.Customer, v.Voucher, v.Date, v.[Value],
             TotalRedeem = r.[Value],
             Redeem = case  when sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer 
                                                          order by v.Date)
                            <=   r.[Value]
                            then v.[Value]
                            when sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer 
                                                          order by v.Date)
                            -    v.[Value] <= r.[Value]
                            then r.[Value] 
                            -    sum(v.[Value]) over (partition by v.Customer 
                                                          order by v.Date)
                            +    v.[Value]
                            else 0
                            end
      from   Vocuher v
             inner join inserted r on v.Customer = r.Customer
      where  v.[Value] > 0
    )
    update r
    set    [Value] = r.[Value] - r.Redeem
    from   redemption r
    where  Redeem > 0

    delete r
    from   inserted i
           inner join PointsToRemove r on i.Customer = r.Customer
end
```

[db<>fiddel trigger demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z7m8LmLu)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,your table lack Unquie row so I have define identity column, you can change it suiting your requirement.

I have use `Recursive CTE` which will definetly suit atleast some thousand rows at one time.

Let me know if it any not working for any particular sample data.

Try this script,

```
declare  @Voucher Table (id int identity(1,1),Customer varchar(50)
,  Voucher varchar(50), dates date ,  vouchervalue int ) 
insert into @Voucher values
('A' ,  'VOC1',    '2023-01-20', 200),
('A' ,  'VOC2' ,   '2023-03-12' ,350),
('A' ,  'VOC3'  ,  '2023-05-03' ,200)


declare  @PointsToRemove Table (Customer varchar(50),  vouchervalue int ) 
insert into @PointsToRemove values
('A' ,  450)

;with CTE as
(
select v.*
,pr.vouchervalue-v.vouchervalue NetVouch
,case when v.vouchervalue-pr.vouchervalue<=0 then 0 else v.vouchervalue-pr.vouchervalue end Vflg
,case when pr.vouchervalue-v.vouchervalue<=0 then 0 else pr.vouchervalue-v.vouchervalue end PRflg
--,case when pr.vouchervalue-v.vouchervalue<=0 then 'V' else 'PR' end flg
from @Voucher V
inner join @PointsToRemove PR on v.Customer=pr.Customer
where id=1

union all

select v.*,pr.NetVouch-v.vouchervalue NetVouch
,case when v.vouchervalue-pr.NetVouch<=0 then 0 else v.vouchervalue-pr.NetVouch end Vflg
,case when pr.NetVouch-v.vouchervalue<=0 then 0 else pr.NetVouch-v.vouchervalue end PRflg
--,case when pr.NetVouch-v.vouchervalue<=0 then 'V' else 'PR' end flg
from @Voucher V
inner join CTE PR on v.Customer=pr.Customer
where v.id=pr.id+1 and  pr.NetVouch>0

)
,CTE1 as
(
select *
, ROW_NUMBER()over(partition  by customer order by id desc)UpdateRow
from CTE
)
--select * from CTE

select * into #temp from CTE1 

select * from #temp

update V
set vouchervalue=Vflg
from @voucher v
inner join #temp t on v.id=t.id

update pr
set vouchervalue=prflg
from @PointsToRemove pr
inner join #temp t on pr.Customer=t.Customer
where t.UpdateRow=1

select * from @Voucher

select * from @PointsToRemove

drop table #temp
```